# Missing x-axis group names in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to output a figure but cannot get the group name labels on the x-axis.

My file looks like this (there are 28 groups for description and 4000 for phenotype):

```
> head(phe)
  description                                phenotype                        p
1 Psychiatric Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder 0.1100099999999999966782
2 Psychiatric Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder 0.5403200000000000224887
3 Psychiatric Attention deficit hyperactivity disorder 0.3870999999999999996447
4 Psychiatric                 Autism spectrum disorder 0.6267700000000000493117
5 Psychiatric                         Bipolar disorder 0.3073100000000000275868
6 Psychiatric          Anxiety disorder (case/control) 0.5001299999999999634781
3939 Neurological               Retrolenticular part of internal capsule radial diusivities 0.14951999999999998625100
3940 Neurological                            Splenium of corpus callosum radial diusivities 0.26679999999999998161471
3941 Neurological                                Superior corona radiata radial diusivities 0.54986999999999996990852
3942 Neurological                   Superior fronto-occipital fasciculus radial diusivities 0.28690999999999999836575
3943 Neurological                       Superior longitudinal fasciculus radial diusivities 0.59540999999999999481304
3944 Neurological                                       Sagittal stratum radial diusivities 0.04544200000000000322364
3945 Neurological                                    Uncinate fasciculus radial diusivities 0.37778000000000000468958
```

and my code looks like this:

```
ylim <- abs(floor(log10(min(phe$p)))) + 2 
nCHR <- length(unique(phe$description))

axis.set <- phe %>% 
  group_by(description) %>% 
  summarize(center = n() / 2)
sig=0.05/nrow(phe)

phewasplot <- ggplot(phe, aes(x=phenotype, y=-log10(p), label=description, color=as.factor(description), size=-log10(p))) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.75) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(sig), color = "grey40", linetype = "dashed") + 
  scale_x_discrete(label = axis.set$description, breaks = axis.set$center) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, ylim)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.5,3)) +
  labs(x = "Phenotypes", 
       y = "-log10(p)") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme( 
    legend.position = "none",
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 8, vjust = 0.5)
  )
```

Essentially what I have is this: 
[image: Attempt at phewas plot]

What I actually want is something like this:

[image: Nice looking plot]

Comment: Have you checked out the [`PheWAS`](https://github.com/PheWAS/PheWAS/) package?

Comment: By default, `ggplot2` will order the x-axis in alphabetical order unless the mapped aesthetic is a factor.  Then it will order the x-axis by level order.  But to group the x-axis labels, you need to use another variable and the function `fct_reorder()` from the forcats R package.  A combination of these can get what you want but I can't code up a formal answer without a minimum working example.

Comment: Go to trick #5:
https://youtu.be/NDHSBUN_rVU?t=584